# Broken Minecraft Speed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I got permanent speed on my character and it won't go away, I tried

`/effect [Username] clear`

and milk. I also jumped off a cliff hoping for it to go away.

Comment: Are you using mods? That could be the issue

Comment: no I'm on a server

Comment: What's your FOV set at?

Comment: It's set at 100, but whenever I run it kicks me off the server for flying

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: OK. When you press <kbd>E</kbd>, you see the potion effect?

Comment: I don't see any effects

Answer (score 3):

The server may have the Essentials plugin, which is common throughout all Bukkit/Spigot servers. You or someone else may have done the `/speed [0-10]` on you. This results in you walking either faster than walking speed `speed > 1` and slower than walking speed `speed < 1`.
If you see the potion effect, it may be either a beacon , plugin, or command block that is initiating speed on you.
Note: You may not see the speed potion effect on you.

Comment: my friend gave me boots and they had the speed effect set on them, I took the boots off and still have the effect right now. We tried doing /speed 1 & 0 to see if it would change the effect but it didn't.

Comment: @kim Well, I can't really help you there now, except for finding the command block and disabling it (unless it's a plugin. If it is, disable that) Ask a developer on the server, or the owner of the server. If you are the owner/developer, then I can't help you there.

Comment: sorry if this is annoying but what happens if you crouch when moving around?

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier You move slower. In 1.9, the height of the player is lower (by about 1/16 of a block (I think)

Comment: but would the server still consider your movement as flying?

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier No, your movement is on the ground, so why _would_ it be considered flying?